# Matlab Transparent PNG (Upside Down/ Smaller Image)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors, alpha-transparency

<s>I am trying to load a transparent image. It seems to work fine in the first part of the code but then fails. Here is the code</s>

```
for l = 1:4
    color = he;
    color(something ~= l) = 0;
    A = ((color(:,:,1)));
    A( all(color == 0, 3 ) ) = 1;
    file = strcat(file{k}, '.png');
    segmented_images{k} = color;
    transparency{k} = A;
    chk = segmented_images{k};
    f = imshow(chk);
    set(f, 'AlphaData', transparency{k});
    figure, imshow(chk), title("Working Fine");
end
```

Here the images appear to be transparent.
If I test it outside the loop:

```
my_alpha = transparency{1};
chk2 = segmented_images{1};
f = imagesc(chk2);
set(f, 'AlphaData', transparency{1});
figure, imshow(chk2),title('transparent Final');    
imwrite(chk2, 'G:\path.png');
```

I see black color in transparent region. If I do this:

```
imwrite(chk2, 'G:\wamp\www\final_check.png', "Alpha", my_alpha);
```

I am able to save a transparent image. I am new to this color processing thing, so do excuse me if I am making a really silly mistake. Thank you

*EDIT*
Inside the loop image is printed twice, first time as transparent and second time with black background. It seems I am not displaying the image in correct way. Plus the title 'Working Fine' is attached to the black background image not to the other one.

EDIT2:

The real problem is that the image with alpha channel are being upside down.[image: These are the four images that I overlay on each other]

What I get as a result is: [image: Upside down, Final images]

This is the code:

```
  figure
  hold on
  h1 = image(segmented_images{1});
  set(h1, 'AlphaData', transparency{1});
  h2 = image(last_image);
  set(h2, 'AlphaData', transparency{2});
  h3 = image(segmented_images{3});
  set(h3, 'AlphaData', transparency{3});
  h4 = image(segmented_images{4});
  set(h4, 'AlphaData', transparency{4});
  hold off;
```

There are two issues here: one the image is smaller and upside down. Am I overlaying it correctly. Again I suspect it would be silly mistake that I can't find. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

When I change

h1 = image(segmented_images{1});

to
 `h1 = imshow(segmented_images{1});` 
I get the desired results. Can somebody explain how getting handler is different? I guess I need to go through documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To change the y-direction use:

```
set ( axesHandle, 'YDir', 'reverse' )
```

Comment: This doesn't completely solve the problem since the image is not only upside down it is also of low quality and smaller.

Comment: without knowing more about your actual images its hard to answer that.  Having said that you do you you can specify the `XData`  and `YData` properties when you call image -> that way you can force them to overlay.